# Algorithm for placing textual/non-textual content in a book layout

Tags: algorithm, layout

Hey guys I was looking for different approaches/algorithms for placing textual/non-textual content in a book layout having 2 sides. So essentially it should look like a user is reading a book & content placed in a 2 page layout. 
If you guys have any directives or suggestions on how to go about doing this. Way to decide how many content items can fit into 2 pages, no overflow. Suppose a page is 425 px BY 600 px & we have 2 such pages fit side by side (dimensions are flexible).
Any pointers appreciated?

P.S. I know this is not a pure programming question per se but more of an algorithmic question. If so, please direct me where this question can be best asked.

**EDIT 1**
I want to use this algorithm in a website application & not in a standalone app, so please consider that.

**EDIT 2**
I would like to mention that the order of the content items is pre-decided.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to display data in a book like format, then the easiest method would be to reuse an already existing toolkit for doing text layout.  I think the best tool for this purpose would be [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/), which is an evolution of the original digital typesetting program.

In order to use it you will have to convert your data into the LaTeX format, which is relatively painless (I have done it several times with several types of data).  In this document you can specify that you want a book format, how large the pages are, and much more.  You can then render the text to pdf/ps and then display the two pages of a "book" side by side.

If what you are looking for is the actual algorithms to do it yourself, you might search around the [TeX](http://www.tug.org/)/LaTeX community for information.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I want to use this algorithm in a website & not in a standalone app.

Comment: @Chantz: Is there any reason you could not generate a pdf/image on the server with LaTeX, and then send that to the web client?  Also, if you really want to typeset by hand you can take a look at the two sites I linked.  Both include resources on the theory of typesetting (which is very, very, very complex).

Comment: the website is supposed to be interactive. Users need to be able to switch on/off certain content. Edit media etc. Everything inside the browser (preferably on the same page.) I will look onto the links now. But is there an easy way out?